# DNN 4.9 ... Intermittent error while uploading PDF files

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I get intermittent "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" errors when uploading PDF files in FCKEditor in DNN 4.9.

Here's the error:

> AssemblyVersion: 04.09.00   AbsoluteURL:
>   /.../Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/fcklinkgallery.aspx
>   UserAgent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR
>   1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; IEMB3; IEMB3)   InnerException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   FileName:
>   FileLineNumber: 0   FileColumnNumber: 0   Method:
>   DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.UrlControl.cmdSave_Click   StackTrace:
>   Message: DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.UrlControl.cmdSave_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The error comes and goes, file size doesn't seem to matter, last time i got it after uploading a couple of 1MB files, the third file (600kB) gave me an error.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this on a number of sites with the FCK provider that is included in 4.9.0 and later versions of DotNetNuke.

At this time I am not aware of any way to "Fix" it, as I have not pinpointed exactly what is causing the error.